# Wireless not working on Lenovo B-575

Tags: connection, lenovo

Help, because without internet, Ubuntu is useless. I can't enable wireless. My physical switch is on, it's working in windows, but I just can't enable wireless. I updated my drivers, and when I goto turn the wireless switch on, I click on, but it immediatley goes back to off. So I turned off airplane mode, but it still goes immediatley back off. Please help, immediately!

Comment: we love to help you - but we need more useful information in your question! run in a terminal `sudo lshw -class network` and `rfkill list all` and copy and paste the output into your question.  Add the version of ubuntu you are using to your question as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have foud this solution:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add a line at the very end:

> blacklist acer_wmi

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add one line above "exit 0":

> rfkill unblock all

(reboot)